# Store multiple laravel session in once

Tags: php, laravel

Hello i'd like to store some laravel sessions in once

so instead of doing like this :

```
// Storing Sessions
        $request->session()->put('term', $request->term);
        $request->session()->put('section', $request->section);

        // Accessing Sessions
        $request->session()->get('term');
        $request->session()->get('section');
```

I want something like :

```
// Storing Sessions
        $sessions = [
            'term' => $request->term,
            'section' => $request->section,
        ];

        $request->session()->put($sessions);

        // Accessing Sessions
        $request->session()->get('term');
        $request->session()->get('section');
```

But couldn't find the way.

I tried something like this , but the code for accesssing is ugly and too long:

```
        $request->session()->put('my-sessions', [
            'term' => $request->term,
            'section' => $request->section,
        ]);

        // Too long
        $request->session()->get('my-sessions')['term'];
        $request->session()->get('my-sessions')['section'];
```

I know foreach will do the job, but Is there more a "Laravel way" or built in function to do that ?

Comment: Have you tried? `session(['term', $request->term, 'section', $request->section]);` or what you wanted `session($sessions)`

Comment: @sta that would be `session(['term' => $request->term, 'section' => $request->section])` its an associative array

Comment: @lagbox really a silly mistake, thanks for the correction

Comment: do you guys mean $request->session()->put(['term' => $request->term,'section' =>$request->section,]); ? it worked ! but it's weird that when i tried to store the array into variable it goes wrong